# Practical storage of many (in single-row) boolean values

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I wish to have stored **many** (**N** ~ about 150) **boolean values** of web app "environment" variables.

What is the proper way to get them stored?

1. creating **N columns** and one (**1**) **row** of data,
2. creating two (**2**) or three (**3**) **columns** *(id smallserial, name varchar(255), value boolean)* with **N rows** of data,
3. by using **jsonb** data type,
4. by using **area** data type,
5. by using **bit string** *bit varying(n)*,
6. by another way (please advise)

Note: *name* may be too long.

Tia!

Comment: What do you mean by efficent? Disk space. Time to do a lookup

Comment: Both would be better I suppose for a complete and integrated answer. Therefore, I add "efficient for: a) disk space, b) time to do a lookup c) other".

Comment: Have you tried just storing a bunch of booleans and seeing how big the table gets etc?

Comment: For N = 238 variables i.e. columns with one (1) row data, "Table size" is only 8192 bytes.

Comment: In a table with (id smallserial, parameter character varying(255), value boolean) and N = 238 rows without indexing defined, "Table size" is 24KB.

Comment: In a table with (parameter jsonb) and N = 238 pairs without indexing defined, "Table size" is 8192 bytes and "Toast table size" is 24KB.

Comment: In a table with (parameter bit varying(238)) and one (1) row data, "Table size" is again 8192 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps use a bit string? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/datatype-bit.html. (Set the nth bit to 1 when the nth attribute would have been "true")

Comment: I added to the list as no.5.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you wants to access them in normal usage.
Do you need to access one of this value at time, in this case JSONB is a really good way, really easy and quick to find a record, or do you need to get all of them in one call, in this case Bit String Types are the best, but you need to be really careful around, order and transcription for writing and reading..

Comment: Both ways would be used. All the variables are "_is_enabled" or "_is_displayed". They would be read one at a time for "making decision" or all together for being stored initially in global variables. Which way is more used in web app development?

Comment: For my own development team we usually used jsonb.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the options will do, depending on your circumstances. There is little need to optimise storage if you have only 150 values. Unless, of course there can be a very large number of these sets of 150 values or you are working in a very restricted environment like an embedded system (in which case a full-blown database client is probably not what you're looking for).

There is no definite answer here, but I will give you a few guidelines to consider. As from experience:

- You don't want to have an anonymous string of values that is interpreted in code. When you change *anything* later on, your 1101011 or 0x12f08a will be rendered an fascinatingly enigmatic problem.
- When the number of your fields starts to grow, you will regret if they are all stored in a single cell on a single row, because you will either be developing some obscure SQL or transforming a larger-than-needed dataset from the server.
- When you feel that boolean values are really not enough, you start to wonder if there is a possibility to store something else too.

Settings and environmental properties are seldom subject to processor or data intensive processing, so follow the easiest path.

As my recommendation based on the given information and some educated guessing, you'll probably want to store your information in a table like

```
string key       | integer set_idx | string value
---------------------------------------------------------
use.the.force    | 1899            | 1
home.directory   | 1899            | /home/dvader
use.the.force    | 1900            | 0
home.directory   | 1900            | /home/yoda
```

Converting a `1` to boolean `true` is cheap, and if you have only one set of values, you can ignore the set index.

Comment: At first read, what I understand is "better avoid using bit string for practical reasons". In addition, I do have only boolean values. There is another table called "parameters" where other types of data are stored in mix.

Comment: This is just a *recommendation* for your future self :) There are times when you want to store data which is a bit field by nature; an anonymous set of switches or an arbitrary bitmap pattern. In this case, each value has semantics, which is best stored with the data, so to avoid error-prone mapping of bit index to the semantic meaning.

Comment: And if you have the table called "parameters", why not store this data there as well? As a developer, these are of course decisions left to you to make.

Comment: Your recommendation is well understood! As regards, the environmental variables and parameters I believe that it is better (for practical reasons again) to separate them. One table has only Boolean data (for decision making) and the other one strings (for file paths), numerals, etc. as parameters.